# ./ not correctly taken into account in URL

Tags: java, url, normalization

I want to resolve some urls. For that, I take the result of :

```
  new URL(new URL(baseurl), link);
```

This method seems to fail when `baseurl="http://www.site.com"` and `link="./"`

You will have the following result `http://www.site.com/./` instead of just `http://www.site.com/`

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work?

`new URI(baseUrl).resolve(link).toURL()`

The [java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) has a resolve method that might be what you're looking for and toURL to get it into a URL.

**EDIT**

The following seems to work for me..

```
import java.net.URL;


public class UrlTest {

    private static URL resolve(URL base, String link) throws Exception {
        if (base.getPath().isEmpty()) {
            link = "/" + link;
        }       
        URL u1 = base.toURI().resolve(link).normalize().toURL();
        return u1;
    }

    private static void resolveUrls(URL baseUrl) throws Exception {
        String link = "abcd";
        String link2 = "./";
        String link3 = "./foo";
        System.out.println(resolve(baseUrl, link));
        System.out.println(resolve(baseUrl, link2));
        System.out.println(resolve(baseUrl, link3));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
        String baseUrlStr = "http://www.somesite.com";
        URL baseUrl = new URL(baseUrlStr);
        resolveUrls(baseUrl);
        baseUrl = new URL(baseUrlStr + "/index.html");
        resolveUrls(baseUrl);
        baseUrl = new URL(baseUrlStr + "/path/index.html");
        resolveUrls(baseUrl);
    }

}
```

Comment: not working properly if link = "abcd" -> will be concatenated directly to the domain

Comment: what about `new URL(baseUrl).toURI().resolve(link).toURL()` - tested and doesn't work.  Now I'm curious :)

Comment: @SB: Your curiosity may be satisfied by the explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
new URL(new URL(baseurl), link.replace("./"), "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`URI.normalize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#normalize%28%29).

```
import java.net.*;

class TestURL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = "http://www.site.com/./";
        URL url = new URL(s);
        System.out.println(url);
        URI uri = url.toURI();
        System.out.println(uri.normalize().toURL());
    }
}
```

### Output

```
http://www.site.com/./
http://www.site.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

*This is a very long and, although informative, largely unhelpful post, but there actually is an answer at the end.*

This is all a bit of a sad story. It is clearly completely mad that this:

```
URI base = new URI("http", "example.org", null, null);
URI link = new URI(null, null, "index.html", null);
System.out.println(base.resolve(link));
```

Should print:

```
http://example.orgindex.html
```

Rather than:

```
http://example.org/index.html
```

And yet it does. Why? Because [`java.net.URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) ...

> represents a URI reference as defined by [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396): Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax

And does so faithfully. In particular, the [`resolve`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#resolve%28java.net.URI%29) method ...

> constructs a new hierarchical URI in a manner consistent with RFC 2396, [section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-5.2)

Sadly, the algorithm specified in section 5.2 is wrong. Specifically, although it says that ...

> the path component is never undefined, though it may be empty

It does not ensure that the result of resolving a relative URI against a base URI which has an empty path is a valid URI. The problem is in step 6, which deals with the merging of the paths from the base and the relative URI into a buffer which will be used to form the resolved URI. The first two sub-steps of step 6 are:

> a) All but the last segment of the base URI's path component is copied to the buffer.  In other words, any characters after the last (right-most) slash character, if any, are excluded.
>
> b) The reference's path component is appended to the buffer string.

If the base URI has an empty path, then after sub-step a, the buffer will be empty. If the relative URI has a path not starting with /, then after sub-step b, the buffer will contain a string not starting with /. The following steps deal with dot normalisation, and do nothing to add a leading /. The final step is:

> h) The remaining buffer string is the reference URI's new path component.

So, the resolved URI has a path which does not start with /. Step 7 then builds this into the final string form of the resolved URI without any provisions for inserting a /. And so, resolution of a relative URI without a leading / against a base URI with an empty path results in nonsense. This is what RFC 2396 specifies, and what `java.net.URI` does.

Whoops!

The story doesn't quite end there. In January 2005, [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) was published. This obsoleted RFC 2396, and contains a new definition of URI resolution, again in [section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2). This definition is completely rewritten in a more rigorous (or at least rigorous-looking) style, and specifies the merging of paths in [section 5.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.3), which starts off by getting this right:

> If the base URI has a defined authority component and an empty path, then return a string consisting of "/" concatenated with the reference's path

So, this whole problem would be fixed if Java was updated to conform to an eight-year-old RFC, rather than a fourteen-year-old one. Doing just that is what is asked for in [bug 6791060](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6791060), which was opened in 2009, and last touched in 2010. Sun, i am disappoint.

Anyway, with this understanding in hand, we can see that the right solution is something like:

```
public static URI fix(URI uri) {
    if (uri.getPath().isEmpty()) {
        try {
            return new URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getAuthority(), "/", uri.getQuery(), uri.getFragment());
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            AssertionError ae = new AssertionError("highly implausible error fixing URI " + uri);
            ae.initCause(e);
            throw ae;
        }
    }
    else {
        return uri;
    }
}

fix(new URI(baseurl)).resolve(link);
```